# Match for two parameters and ranges

Tags: rust, match, traits

I'm trying to implement a quadrant trait for a 2-dimensional point and confused on how to match over 2 struct fields with ranges. My struct is defined as:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point<T, U> {
  x: T, // so I can have float and int for x and y, sure
  y: U,
}

impl<T, U> Point<T, U> {
    fn x(&self) -> &T {
        &self.x // make convenient accessors
    }
    
    fn y(&self) -> &U {
        &self.y
    }
}
```

I define this trait:

```rust
pub trait Quadrant {
    fn quadrant(&self) -> String; // define the trait
}
```

And I try to implement it for the `Point` struct:

```rust
//now implement the trait for your point
impl<T,U> Quadrant for Point<T,U> {
    fn quadrant(&self) -> String {
        match self {
            (self::x() > 0 && self::y() > 0) => "I",
            (self::x() > 0 && self::y() < 0) => "IV",
            (self::x() < 0 && self::y() > 0) => "II",
            (self::x() < 0 && self::y() < 0) => "III",
            (self::x() == 0 && self::y() == 0) => "ORIGIN",
            _ => "AXIS",
        }
    }
}
```

My error is:

```
(self::x() > 0 && self::y() > 0) => "I",
           ^ expected one of `)`, `,`, or `|`, found `>`
```

It's not clear to me how to do this match block on `self.x()` and `self.y()` for all ranges.

I'd like to be able to say:

```rust
fn main() {
  let p1 = Point { x: 5, y: 10 };
  println!("p1 is in Quadrant={:?}", p1.quadrant());
}
```

With the output `p1 is in Quadrant I`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arms of a match block need of the form `<pattern> [conditions]`. If all you have are conditions you could write a plain old `if`-`else` chain:

```
fn quadrant(&self) -> &'static str {
    if self.x() > 0 && self.y() > 0 {
        "I"
    } else if self.x() < 0 && self.y() > 0 {
        "II"
    } else if self.x() < 0 && self.y() < 0 {
        "III"
    } else if self.x() > 0 && self.y() < 0 {
        "IV"
    } else if self.x() == 0 && self.y() == 0 {
        "ORIGIN"
    } else {
        "AXIS"
    }
}
```

For a `match` block to make sense you'll want to pull out one or more values so that there's something to pattern match against. You could put the x and y coordinates in a tuple:

```
fn quadrant(&self) -> &'static str {
    match (self.x(), self.y()) {
        (x, y) if x > 0 && y > 0 => "I",
        (x, y) if x < 0 && y > 0 => "II",
        (x, y) if x < 0 && y < 0 => "III",
        (x, y) if x > 0 && y < 0 => "IV",
        (0, 0) => "ORIGIN",
        _ => "AXIS",
    }
}
```

This works, but it's pretty much just an `if`-`else` chain in disguise. It would be better if it didn't repeat the comparisons in each arm. We can make it a proper `match` block by calling [`cmp`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#tymethod.cmp) and matching on [`Ordering`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html) values:

```
fn quadrant(&self) -> &'static str {
    use std::cmp::Ordering::{Equal, Greater, Less};
    
    match (self.x().cmp(&0), self.y().cmp(&0)) {
        (Greater, Greater) => "I",
        (Less, Greater) => "II",
        (Less, Less) => "III",
        (Greater, Less) => "IV",
        (Equal, Equal) => "ORIGIN",
        (Equal, _) | (_, Equal) => "AXIS",
    }
}
```

What I like about this is that it makes it clear that an `"AXIS"` is where one value or the other is equal to zero. By writing it this way instead of with a catch-all `_ => "AXIS"` arm the compiler can check that we've covered all of the possibilities. If we were missing a case the code wouldn't compile.

Other notes:

- Call receiver methods with `self.x()` rather than `self::x()`. Colons are for calling static methods, as in `Self::x()`, if `x` didn't take a `&self` parameter.
- If you return `&'static str` instead of `String` then you can return the literals directly. If the return type is `String` then you'll need to call `String::from` or `.into()` or one of the other `String`-construction methods to convert the static literals into heap-allocated `String`s.
- Even better, make `Quadrant` an enum instead of a trait so you can return strongly typed enum values.
- I would recommend making `x` and `y` public variables and ditching the getters. Hiding variables and providing getters is an anti-pattern in Rust. It's not always wrong, but it's not something one should habitually do like one might in an OO language that promotes heavy encapsulation.

  ```
  struct Point<T, U> {
      pub x: T,
      pub y: U,
  }
  ```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  When I make x and y public, I'm getting this error I don't understand: `    match (self.x.cmp(&0), self.y.cmp(&0)) {
                  ^^^ `T` is not an iterator`

Comment: This is a great answer. I think I'll raise my follow ups in a second question.  Thanks!